# Check if macro argument has specific prefix

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

I'm writing a math paper, and I've got macros which take labels of theorems, corollaries, etc. as arguments. I'm wondering, is there a way to check if the label starts with a particular prefix?

That is, a command `\reftitle` which does "Theorem" for `\reftitle{thm:122}`, "Corollary" for `\reftitle{cor:124}`, "Statement" for `\reftitle{stmt:122}`.

The idea is the macro needs to check if the argument starts with `cor`, `thm`, etc.

I'm very new to macros in LaTeX, but I haven't been able to find how to do this. Anybody have ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\def\reftitle#1{\xreftitle#1:\relax}
\def\xreftitle#1:#2\relax{%
\def\tmp{#1}%
\def\tmpb{thm}\ifx\tmp\tmpb Theorem\fi
\def\tmpb{cor}\ifx\tmp\tmpb Corollary\fi
}




a \reftitle{thm:foo}

b \reftitle{cor:foo}

c \reftitle{foo}
```

However rather than relying on label prefixes it is perhaps better to record the type of unit that is being referenced automatically at the time of the `\label` (as hyperref does for example)